# Selenium + Java: How to get the OS, and Browser details on run time?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

What I want to do is, while I'm running my tests, I want to get the current,

1. Operating System
2. Browser Name
3. Browser Version

This is for making the details clear in the test/bug report.
I haven't tried any solution yet as I'm new to Selenium and am not aware if it can be done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes is possible using Selenium with the "**Capabilities**" class.

Here is sample code you can use to get the details you need:

```
Capabilities caps = ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities();
String browserName = caps.getBrowserName().toLowerCase();
String OS = caps.getPlatform().toString();
String BV = caps.getVersion().toString();
System.out.println("OS: " + OS + ", Browser: " + browserName + " V " + BV);
```

Comment: Wow! that was simple. This helps a lot.